# Kafka - What are the better alternatives than poll() to listen to a topic in Java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to create a consumer client in Java. I realized the poll() function is depreciated. What are the alternatives to listen to a topic of Kafka?

My code:

```
KafkaConsumer< String, UserSegmentPayload > kc = new KafkaConsumer<>(props2);
kc.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topicName));
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, UserSegmentPayload> records = kc.poll(100);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, UserSegmentPayload> record : records) {
        System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n",
        record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
    }
}
```

Comment: From my point of view a seperate Processor class that is included in a Kafka-Topology is more elegant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason `poll()` and `poll(long)` are deprecated is that they may block indefinitely (even in the second case, where a timeout is specified). The root cause for this behaviour is that an initial metadata update in those methods may block forever (see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-266%3A+Fix+consumer+indefinite+blocking+behavior)). Instead, you should use the `poll(Duration)`-method of the `KafkaConsumer`. So, in your code, all you have to do is to replace `kc.poll(100)` with `kc.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100))`.

Comment: According to Kafka documentation, poll method has the parameter timeout with type java.time.Duration. More details can be found through below link.
 https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#poll-java.time.Duration-