# Returning values from kafka consumer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I am working on a scala application. I am using kafka in it. I am to consume message from kafka topic. Since I am writing a test case, I need to get record do some assertion to get pass my testcase. I am using following code to consume kafka message:

```
import java.util.{Collections, Properties}
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
object KafkaConsumerSubscribeApp extends App {

  val props:Properties = new Properties()
  props.put("group.id", "test")
  props.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")
  props.put("key.deserializer",
      "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer") 
  Props.put("value.deserializer",
      "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true")
  props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000")
  val consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props)
  val topics = List("topic_text")
  try {
    consumer.subscribe(topics.asJava)
    while (true) {
      val records = consumer.poll(10)
      for (record <- records.asScala) {
        println("Topic: " + record.topic() + 
                 ",Key: " + record.key() +  
                 ",Value: " + record.value() +
                 ", Offset: " + record.offset() + 
                 ", Partition: " + record.partition())
      }
    }
  }catch{
    case e:Exception => e.printStackTrace()
  }finally {
    consumer.close()
  }
}
```

There are two problems I am facing with this code. In intellij it is giving warning that poll method is deprecated. How can I modify this code for deprecation? Second problem is I want to this method to return the message which it gets from kafka topic. That message is in record.value(). How can I return it? With this code since while(true) is used, so it will be a endless loop and it will keep listening to messages from topic. How can I return record.value() from this method so that I can use data which I got from topic in other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return you have to modify the codebase as follows. To remove the deprecation of the poll, you need to just pass the durations. For more info [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943786/kafka-what-are-the-better-alternatives-than-poll-to-listen-to-a-topic-in-jav)

```
def readFromKafka(//arguments) = {
 // other code

 consumer.subscribe(util.Collections.singletonList(topic))
 consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(5000)).asScala.toList.map(_.value())
}
```

To keep on reading from Kafka, you have to keep on calling the function. For that, you may use the scheduler.
I hope it will help.

Comment: Hi How it is returning value?

Comment: The last statement is returning a value. For reference, you can refer the https://github.com/mahesh2492/embedded-kafka/blob/master/src/main/scala/consumer/CustomConsumer.scala

Comment: Hi Do  you have answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63028617/getting-values-from-kafka-consumer?noredirect=1#comment111458997_63028617

Comment: I never worked on alpakka. Check documentation, it won't look tough.

Comment: The code you suggested gives result as json? I want result  as json. What to do if this code doesnn't give record as json

Comment: Why you passed user in Kafkaconsumer? Why returning List of Users?

Comment: I didn't pass User, I am reading a data of user from topic and returning it. Clone it and read producer and consumer you will get it. It is basic kafka producer consumer application.

Comment: Also If I have XML data in my kafka consume. Will this code fetch it?

Comment: Is it the Duration from import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration or something else?

Comment: Because poll method is not taking import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

Comment: you code on github is giving List of last two three values. When I printed offsets. it is giving list of last three offsets. May I know the reason? How it is working? How can I get just the record which my just published

Comment: I think you need to study kafka first. I can not explain you here in comments.

Comment: Yes I am using it for the first time but I imeediatley needs this answer so I  asked